# Definite integral of even and odd functions proof

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be continous on [-a,a]

a) prove : $\int^{a}_{-a} f(x) dx = 0$

Because $f$ is odd $f(-x) = -f(x)$

$$\int_{x=-a}^0 f(x) \, dx = \int_{x=-a}^0 -f(-x) \, dx$$

letting $t = -x, dt = -dx$

$\int_{x=-a}^0 -f(-x) \, dx = \int_{t=a}^0 f(t) \, dt$

$\int_{t=a}^0 f(t) \, dt = -\int_{t=0}^a f(t) \, dt$

$\int_{-a}^{a}f(x)dx=\int_{-a}^{0}f(x)dx+\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx$

$\int_{-a}^{a}f(x)dx=-\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx+\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx$=0

b) prove : $\int_{-a}^{a}f(x)dx=2\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx$

Because $f$ is even : $f(x) =f(-x)$

letting $t = -x, dt = -dx$

$\int_{x=-a}^0 f(-x) \, dx = -\int_{u=a}^0 f(t) \, dt$=$\int_{u=0}^a f(t)dt$

Because $t$ is a dummy variable it can be replaced by x.

Is this rigorous proof ( is there any flaws? ) or is there better way of proving this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are assuming what you want to prove.

Comment: I did not assume that , I just meant to write what am gonna to prove on the top to make it easy to follow .

Comment: Is it given that the function is odd and thus you prove that the integral is zero, or is it given that the integral is zero and thus the function is odd? That's not clear. It seems like the second, but then the trouble starts with your second line" because the function...."

Comment: I changed that thanks for the comment.

Comment: "where $f$ is *continuous*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be nit picking but your proof should be as follows:

Assume $f$ is odd. First observe
\begin{align}
\int^a_{-a}f(x)\ dx = \int^a_0 f(x)\ dx + \int^{0}_{-a} f(x)\ dx.
\end{align}
Using $x=-u$ substitution in the second integral yields
\begin{align}
\int^0_{-a} f(x)\ dx = -\int^0_{a} f(-u)\ du= \int^a_0 f(-u)\ du.
\end{align}
And since $f$ is odd, then it follows
\begin{align}
\int^a_0 f(-u)\ du = -\int^a_0 f(u)\ du
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\int^a_{-a} f(x)\ dx = \int^a_0 f(x)\ dx -\int^a_0 f(u)\ du = 0.
\end{align}

Comment: nit picking is sometimes needed to make the prove good. +1